# How do I set the Python interpreter with JEP (Java Embedded Python)?

Tags: python, jepp

I am trying to get the Java Embedded Python API (JEP) run with a custom-installed Python environment. Right now, it runs the default interpreter.

It has been suggested here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jep-project/1IzoddwEILE

to set the PATH and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the custom-installed environment for JEP to fire up the "right" interpreter from that environment (instead of the default one).

However, even when I do that, it is still the old default system interpreter that gets executed. Any ideas why?